# The correct tenses pairs for main and sub clauses

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

> A: The goods that he bought yesterday **are** a car, a television, and a bunch of candies.
>
> B: The goods that he bought yesterday **were** a car, a television, and a bunch of candies.

Which one is the correct pair of tenses?

Comment: Sorry but they both sound wrong to me.  "Goods" is a generic plural, so using it for a singular direct object doesn't sound right.  Correct usage:  The goods that he bought yesterday **were** a car, a bike, and a gallon of ice cream.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically correct. The context will determine the usage of are or were.

Comment: @Josh: Can you make an answer by specifying the context as well?

Comment: @SingleFighter I added details to my answer to address the issue of context.

Comment: Eventually I need 13 months to understand this problem.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, it's a tough problem. @RaceYouAnytime gave a fluent and very thorough answer below that works for tests but still doesn't quite reflect how people will actually speak. It really depends on whether the items still exist and whether the speaker is emphasizing the time of their purchase or their present status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **yesterday** is in the past, you would generally use **were**, regardless of whether "goods" is a generic plural or not.

See [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/were) of "were" from Merriam-Webster:

> past tense second-person singular, past tense plural, and past subjunctive of *be*

In your case, "yesterday" indicates that it's likely past tense plural.  Even if what you wanted was past-tense singular, you wouldn't say **are**, you would say **was**, [per this definition of "was" from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/was):

> past tense first- and third-person singular of *be*

But as you can tell, it would sound unnatural to say

> The goods was

So we can conclude that "the goods" should be treated as plural.

The one caveat is that the sentence could refer to goods that continue to exist now, and refer to the state that they're in now.  If you want to specifically refer to their present condition, you would use "are" as *present tense plural.*

> The apples that he bought yesterday **are** *turning brown*.

However, unless you are specifically adding context relevant to the present state of the goods, you would assume past tense because of the word yesterday.

> The apples that he bought yesterday **were** a combination of McIntosh and Red Delicious.

In your case, because there is no additional context relevant to present tense, you want to use **were**.

> The goods that he bought yesterday **were** a car, a television, and a bunch of candies.

Comment: This is very good and deserves the bounty, except for the idea that the present tense is uncommon either formally or informally... As long as the emphasis is on the objects rather than the action of their purchase, it's *more* rather than less likely that they would be referred to in the present tense.

Comment: The *yesterday* modifies the time of *buy* (which must be past tense) and the tense of the other verb is relatively free to vary as the speaker wishes.